# How to select specific characters in a string in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have an array

```
     a = ["something_another_some","another_some_thing","123_456_456"];

     I want to save only like this

    b =["something","something","123"];
    c  = ["something_another","another_some","123_456"]; 
    d= ["some","some","456"];(words after second "_")
    e= ["another","some","456"];(words between two "_" )
```

how to write jquery code for this

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simple:

```
var a = ["something_another_some",
         "another_some_thing",
         "123_456_789"];
var b = [],
    c = [],
    d = [],
    e = [];

for( var i=0; a[i]; i++){

    var firstPos = a[i].indexOf("_");
    var secPos = a[i].indexOf("_", firstPos+1);

    b.push( a[i].substring(0, firstPos) );
    c.push( a[i].substring(0, secPos) );
    d.push( a[i].substring(secPos+1, a[i].length) );
    e.push( a[i].substring(firstPos+1, secPos) );

}

alert( 
    'b :\n' + b.join('\n') + '\n\n' + 
    'c :\n' + c.join('\n') + '\n\n' + 
    'd :\n' + d.join('\n') + '\n\n' +
    'e :\n' + e.join('\n')
);
```

---

Live: http://jsfiddle.net/j49cgky7/3/

Comment: I edited it again can you check it once I'm newbie to jquery thanks!!

Comment: You can do it! all words of the string are between _0_ or _firstPos_ or _secPos_ or _a[i].length_ ... try it yourself now